# sending my form data HTML to an email using SMTP server

Tags: php, html, forms, email, phpmailer

I am trying to get my for data to pass through my php code and email me from my gmail account to another email address. But having problems doing so.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="sendMail.php">

<table width="400px">

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="last_name">Last Name </label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="email">Email *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="telephone">Phone</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">

 </td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

PHP code sendMail.php

```
<?php 

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'myname@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'H********';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

$mail->From = 'myname@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'TEST';
$mail->addAddress('myname@domain.com');

$errors = '';

if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||
   empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['phone']) ||
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail;



mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$email_subject = "Request Additional Information: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new request for additional information. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
"Email: $email_address\n  Phone: $phone\n  Message: \n $message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
}


?>
```

Can someone help me by figuring out why when I send it, it comes from the email that the user inputted in from my form and not from my Gmail email address.

Comment: you have 2 chunks of code the first is for `phpMailer` the second is using PHPs `mail` function, the first `phpMailer` never sends anything, the second `mail` does.  Follow the examples here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your Html Code

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="sendMail.php">

<table width="400px">

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="last_name">Last Name </label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="email">Email *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="email" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="telephone">Phone</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">

 </td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Here your sendMail.php

```
    <?php
$first_name="First Name : ".$_POST['first_name']."<br>";
$last_name="Last Name :". $_POST['last_name']. "<br>";
$your_email="Your Email :".$_POST['email']. "<br>";
$telephone="Your Telephone :".$_POST['telephone']. "<br>";
$your_message="Your Comments :".$_POST['comments']. "<br>";
$message = "
 \n $first_name \n 
 \n $last_name \n  
 \n $your_email \n 
 \n $telephone \n 
 \n $your_message \n
";
echo $message;
include "PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php"; 


$mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->isSMTP();                                      
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;          
 $mail->Username = '***@gmail.com';
 $mail->Password = 'gmailpassword';           
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';              
 $mail->Port = 587;                      
 $mail->setFrom('someaddress@example.com', 'Mailer');
 $mail->addAddress($your_email, 'Name');
 $mail->addAttachment('fileaddress');       
 $mail->isHTML(true);                              
 $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
 $mail->Body    = $message;
 $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

 if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
 }
?>
```

try this its working fine..!!